# PHP \uXXXX encoded string convert to utf-8

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8

I've got such strings

```
\u041d\u0418\u041a\u041e\u041b\u0410\u0415\u0412
```

How can I convert this to utf-8 encoding?
And what is the encoding of given string?
Thank you for participating!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The simple approach would be to wrap your string into double quotes and let [`json_decode`](http://php.net/json_decode) convert the `\u0000` escapes. (Which happen to be Javascript string syntax.)

```
 $str = json_decode("\"$str\"");
```

Seems to be russian letters: `НИКОЛАЕВ`  (It's already UTF-8 when `json_decode` returns it.)

Answer (score 1):

To parse that string in PHP you can use [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) because JSON supports that unicode literal format.

Comment: `json_decode` returns an UTF-8 string, using `utf8_encode` again would not be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

To preface, you generally should not be encountering `\uXXXX` unicode escape sequences outside of JSON documents, in which case you should be *decoding those documents* using [`json_decode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode) rather than trying to cherry-pick strings out of the middle by hand.

If you want to generate JSON documents *without* unicode escape sequences, then you should use the `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` flag in [`json_encode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php). However, the escapes are default as they are most likely to be safely transmitted through various intermediate systems. I would strongly recommend leaving escapes enabled unless you have a solid reason not to.

Lastly, if you're just looking for something to make unicode text "safe" in some fashion, please instead read over the following SO masterpost: [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

If, after three paragraphs of "don't do this", you still want to do this, then here are a couple functions for applying/removing `\uXXXX` escapes in arbitrary text:

```php
<?php

function utf8_escape($input) {
    $output = '';
    for( $i=0,$l=mb_strlen($input); $i<$l; ++$i ) {
        $cur = mb_substr($input, $i, 1);
        if( strlen($cur) === 1 ) {
            $output .= $cur;
        } else {
            $output .= sprintf('\\u%04x', mb_ord($cur));
        }
    }
    return $output;
}

function utf8_unescape($input) {
    return preg_replace_callback(
        '/\\\\u([0-9a-fA-F]{4})/',
        function($a) {
            return mb_chr(hexdec($a[1]));
        },
        $input
    );
}

$u_input = 'hello world, 私のホバークラフトはうなぎで満たされています';
$e_input = 'hello world, \u79c1\u306e\u30db\u30d0\u30fc\u30af\u30e9\u30d5\u30c8\u306f\u3046\u306a\u304e\u3067\u6e80\u305f\u3055\u308c\u3066\u3044\u307e\u3059';

var_dump(
    utf8_escape($u_input),
    utf8_unescape($e_input)
);
```

Output:

```
string(145) "hello world, \u79c1\u306e\u30db\u30d0\u30fc\u30af\u30e9\u30d5\u30c8\u306f\u3046\u306a\u304e\u3067\u6e80\u305f\u3055\u308c\u3066\u3044\u307e\u3059"
string(79) "hello world, 私のホバークラフトはうなぎで満たされています"
```