# Convert UTF8 characters returned from Facebook Graph API

Tags: php, facebook, json, facebook-graph-api

The character is UTF8 encoded, like..

"\u676f\u845b"

How to convert it back to normal UTF8 string in PHP?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP \uXXXX encoded string convert to utf-8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7894206/php-uxxxx-encoded-string-convert-to-utf-8)

Comment: and yes, `json_decode` handles this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://webarto.com/83/php-unicode_decode-5.3
demo: http://ideone.com/AtY0v

```
function decode_encoded_utf8($string){
    return preg_replace_callback('#\\\\u([0-9a-f]{4})#ism', function($matches) { return mb_convert_encoding(pack("H*", $matches[1]), "UTF-8", "UCS-2BE"); }, $string);
}
 
echo unicode_decode('\u676f\u845b'); # 杯葛
```

Answer (score 2):

The simple approach would be to wrap your string into double quotes and let [`json_decode`](http://php.net/json_decode) convert the `\u0000` escapes. (Which happen to be Javascript string syntax.)

```
 $str = json_decode("\"$str\"");
```

Seems to be asian letters: `杯葛`  (It's already UTF-8 when `json_decode` returns it.)

([Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7894206/php-uxxxx-encoded-string-convert-to-utf-8/7894269#7894269))

Comment: Yes!  This is actually the correct answer.  json decoding packages are well-maintained and cared for, some function that was copied/pasted to stackoverflow is not.